# Field generated by separable element is separable using primitive element theorem?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field. Let $\alpha$ be the root of some separable polynomial $p(x) \in k[x]$. How would one prove that $K = k(\alpha)$ is separable? If possible, I do not want proofs that use the definition of $K$ is separable in terms of "$K$ is $deg(p)$ embeddings into the algebraic closure $\overline k$.

I wish to use use the primitive element theorem, since I know how to prove it [reasoning purely by polynomials](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Egreenber/MATH404-PrimElem.pdf), and I am told that it characterizes separable fields.

By the primitive element theorem, I mean the general version, which states:

> A finite extension $F/k$ is simple (ie, is of the form $k(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in F)$ iff there a finite number of intermediate fields $k \subseteq E \subseteq F$

Comment: It depends what you call "the primitive element theorem". Usually the statement is "a finite separable field extension is simple (generated by one element)". That cannot be used to prove that an extension is separable. Did you have another statement in mind?

Comment: The sum and product of separable elements is separable. It becomes clear that $K$ has to be separable over $k$. I'm not sure how you use the primitive element theorem directly.

Comment: I added what I meant by "primitive element theorem". @green frog how does one see that the sum and product of separable elements is separable?